# How to transform bash output to bash table

Tags: bash, awk, sed, table

My output after running a program in bash looks like this (two rows, : limiter, four columns of data)

`#003:BMW:11:36`

`#004:Audi:2:35`

I would like to convert that to a bash table like this

| Number | Car | ID | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #003 | BMW | 11 | 36 |
| #004 | Audi | 2 | 35 |

Is it possible to use sed/awk for this? My data doesn't come from a file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site! can you define a table? for what kind of output you are saying table? what is the _bash table_ means? you want replace colon delimiters with Tabs/Spaces?or do you want to build a fixed length lines? please [edit] your question and clarify these, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
process-generating-output | sed '1i Number:Car:ID:Cost\n' | column -s: -t
```

Outputs:

```
Number  Car   ID  Cost
#003    BMW   11  36
#004    Audi  2   35
```

We insert a line with the sed command `1i` where we put the column names -
separated by colons just as you columns are in your
'process-generating-output'. Then pipe all that through the column command to
align it nicely.

(Thanks to @Frédéric Loyer for a better way to insert the column names!)

Comment: That works great! Just one more thing - can I somehow add (alligned) column names? If I used sed command to insert names into the 1st line, the names are not aligned with the columns.

Comment: @Blaine44 I updated the answer to add column names. There may be a cleaner way to do this, but it works.

Comment: Using `1s/^/…\n/` to insert a line seems me unnatural. Using `1i…` is simpler.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Ah that is nice - I didn't know about the `1i` possibility. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to have the data formatted like

```
| Number | Car  | ID | Cost |
| ------ | ---- | -- | ---- |
| #003   | BMW  | 11 |   36 |
| #004   | Audi |  2 |   35 |
```

The `csvlook` command from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does this for you, if you first insert the headers.

You may insert the headers by editing your file (or causing your data-generator command to emit them), adding a line saying `Number:Car:ID:Cost` at the start, or you may provide the header line on the fly:

```bsh
$ { echo Number:Car:ID:Cost; cat file; } | csvlook
| Number | Car  | ID | Cost |
| ------ | ---- | -- | ---- |
| #003   | BMW  | 11 |   36 |
| #004   | Audi |  2 |   35 |
```

Above, the `csvlook` command detects that the data is a CSV document using `:` as its field delimiter (this could also be explicitly specified using `-d :`), and produces the formatted table.

**Note that `cat file` may be replaced by any command producing the data as output.**

The final output from `csvlook` is valid Markdown code which, on this site, renders like this:

| Number | Car | ID | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #003 | BMW | 11 | 36 |
| #004 | Audi | 2 | 35 |

Treating the input as CSV allows us to support fields containing quoted `:` characters:

```bsh
$ cat file
#003:BMW:11:36
#004:Audi:2:35
#005:Saab:99:"1:50"
```

```bsh
$ { echo Number:Car:ID:Cost; cat file; } | csvlook
| Number | Car  | ID | Cost |
| ------ | ---- | -- | ---- |
| #003   | BMW  | 11 | 36   |
| #004   | Audi |  2 | 35   |
| #005   | Saab | 99 | 1:50 |
```

Comment: +1 Goodbye cumbersome vim macros to make markdown tables, hello `:!csvlook`

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output stream to the next line:

```bsh
| column -ts: -o$'\t' -N Number,Car,ID,Cost
```

Perhaps the `-o$'\t'` (`--output-separator`) option will need to be omitted.